# Update data with RIA Services over SOAP

Tags: silverlight, wcf, soap, datacontext, ria

I have an SL Application which uses RIA and Domain services for data access. I have modified this to work on SOAP so any other applications can use the service.

On a Windows client I can query data without a problem. But I need to make some update and inserts. As you may know all insert, update, delete methods are not visible over wire through RIA services for SOAP. My understanding is that this is handled by the Domain service and all we need to do is call Submit changes.

Apart from using an [Invoke] attribute and having a method to directly update data, is there any other way I can utilize Domain services to actually do the update operations from the client side.
E.g 
private userDomainContext context = new userDomainContext;

context.Users.Add(user);

I can't seem to find a way to do this from the client side.

Is this the right way or is there a different pattern to be following when using RIA over SOAP.

Kodi.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/03/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-soap-endpoint-3-5.aspx), I am demonstrating how to do CRUD operations from a WPF and a Windows Phone 7 clients using the SOAP endpoint.

It should help you.